# How can I select layer by location AND attributes in ArcMap?

Tags: geospatial, arcgis, arcmap

I have a dataset (i.e. a shapefile) containing spatial location data (coordinates) and elevation data as well as other attribute fields.

I want to select points which have at least 200m vertical separation (i.e. are at least 200m apart on the z-axis) AND are within 3km of each other.

The aim is to create a new shapefile with all points that have this relationship with 1 or more other points.

Im sure there is a solution to this problem (maybe not using arcmap at all?) but i just cant find it. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Chris

Comment: I thought about the problem overnight and i think i might need to re-phrase the question.

What i need to do is:

Select a point if it has another point within 3km of it that has a height of either >200m above or below the first point.


obviously this needs to be done for every single point (and i have ~150,000 points of data).

i think i might end up having to do this via python code.

i dont suppose anyone would know how to do that??

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have much better luck asking this question in gis.stackexchange.com. Many more ESRI users/programmers there. As a matter of fact I bet you find your solution there without having to ask the question.

Comment: Thanks ill take a look there i hadnt heard of that site. many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can run the ArcGIS Near tool on all the points.

Then select by attribute points with Z values of >200m and distance values of <3000m.